# Apply for SS News gallery chatroom

Tags: discussion, chat

If you are

- a SciFi.SE user with 10k+ reputation
- a Sci-Fi News junkie
- interested in sharing hot buzzwords from Sci-Fi world

You can apply for SS News. I'll love to have you.

Comment: Not sure why this has been so heavily downvoted ... also not sure why you couldn't just post the occasional newsflash in Mos Eisley, as others do?

Comment: @randal'thor: both comments - my thoughts exactly.

Comment: Why does this require 10k+ reputation?

Comment: @randal'thor The community's agreement with your second comment might be the explanation for your first one.

Comment: @TARS 10k+ reputation would ensure user's credibility, dedication to site etc.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 - I didn't hit 10K rep until over 3 years, and I have several dozen well recieved questions and answers, hundreds of edits and flags, and thousands of reviews, and a couple dozen meta posts. Yet up until a few upvotes ago, i would be ineligible. I'm sure there are other users just as dedicated to the site who have 800 fewer rep than me. Excluding them wouldn't do any good (and would eliminate from you another possible discusser)

Answer (score 6):

A couple rebuttals:

1) - I didn't hit 10K rep until over 3 years, and I have several dozen well recieved questions and answers, hundreds of edits and flags, and thousands of reviews, and a couple dozen meta posts. Yet up until a few upvotes ago, I would have been ineligible. I'm sure there are other users just as dedicated to the site who have 800 fewer rep than me. Excluding them wouldn't do any good (and would eliminate from you another possible discusser).

2) The very fact someone is on this site means they're some sort of Sci-fi news junkie. Even the person who only follows one niche storyline probably has knowledge of news in thar area that you and most others don't.

3) I don't know exactly what you mean by `sharing hot buzzwords`, but I can't imagine there are enough new "buzzwords" to warrant its own chat room. Most secondary chat rooms here tend to stay pretty empty.

As some others have pointed out, it would probably be more efficient to post the latest news in [Mos Eisley](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley). If you *did* create a separate room, it is my opinion you would be missing out on large sources of potential news and unfairly excluding the biggest segment of the SFF.SE community. **I think it's great you want to share your love of Sci-Fi, I just think there's a better way to do it.**

Comment: In all fairness, i think #3 point is because one of the intents of having a separate room is to avoid ticking off people who object to spoilers.

Comment: @DVK - that makes sense, but if that were the case, it would be better to have individual temporary chatrooms for each upcoming major release